# Problem about $n$ six-sided dice and the sum of the values

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, dice

(AHSME 1994) When $n$ standard six-sided dice are rolled, the probability of
obtaining a sum of 1994 is greater than zero and is the same as the probability of
obtaining a sum of $S$. What is the smallest possible value of $S$?

(I've been trying to use generating function, but without success. I took this one from The Art and Craft of Problem Solving - Paul Zeitz, second ed, pag. 8, chapter 1 exercise 1.3.6.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you roll $n$ dice, the total must be an integer in the interval $[n,6n]$. For $n\le k\le 3n$, the probability of getting a total of $k$ is the same as the probability of getting a total of $7n-k$: each roll that gives you $k$ corresponds to one that gives you $7n-k$ by turning each die over. For $n>1$ these pairs are the only totals with equal probability.

In order for the total $1994$ to be possible, you must have $333\le n\le 1994$. The complementary sum $S$ will be $7n-1994$, and you want to choose $n$ to make this as small as possible. Clearly this is achieved when $n$ is as small as possible, i.e., $333$, in which case $S=7\cdot333-1994=337$.

Comment: I understood, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't first inequality be $n\le k\le 6n$? One-character edit is not allowed.

Comment: @Oleksandr: Either works: when I wrote it I was thinking specifically of matching the lower number of a pair with the higher, so I used the range that covered the lower numbers only.

Comment: I don't really seem to understand this... Since the dice are all standard (= every number has an equal chance of occurring), and there are a minimum of 333 dice to make 1994 happen, shouldn't the sum simply be 333 (the smallest possible number is 1)?

Comment: @space: (Apparently I missed this when I was taking a break in 2017, but for the benefit of future readers I’ll answer it now.) You need to choose $S$ so that its probability is the same as that of $1994$. With $333$ dice there is only one way to get a sum of $333$, but there are many ways to get a sum of $1994$, so the probabilities are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

You need $n \geq333$ to roll $1994$. Imagine a row of $6$s. You need to subtract $1$ from some of them $4$ times to get $1994$. Action of the same number of possibilities would be if we replaced $6$  with $1$ and subtracting to adding. Then the sum would be $337$.

In general, $n$ satisfies $6n > 1994$ and the sum is $n+(6n-1994) = 7n-1994$ so there is no point in considering larger $n$.

Comment: hummm. Very nice way to solve it, i like it. thanks

Comment: Pedantry: $n$ satisfies $6n \ge 1994 \,$ rather than $6n \gt 1994$, though it makes no difference here.