# When n standard six-sided dice are rolled, the probability of obtaining a sum of 1994 is greater than zero

Tags: probability, solution-verification, combinations

> When $n$ standard six-sided dice are rolled, the probability of obtaining a sum of $1994$ is $>0$ and is the same as the probability of obtaining a sum of $S$. What is the smallest possible value of $S$?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197693/693059) has been asked before on MSE, but I had one doubt that wasn't in any of the answers.

To obtain the least sum $S$ we need the least number of dices. For the least number of dices $n$ to give the sum of throws as $1994$, we need all the throws to be $6$ or as close to it. As $1994$ is not divisible by $6$ we can either take $332$ rolls giving $6$ and $1$ roll giving $2$$(332×6+1×2=1992+2=1994)$ or $329$ rolls giving $6$ and $4$ rolls giving $5$$(329×6+5×4=1974+20=1994)$

Now this is where I have a problem. In the second approach, to get the least sum we would need $4$ rolls to give $2$ and rest to give $1$ for least sum $S$
and to satisfy having same probability of occuring. But in the first approach we only need $1$ of the rolls to be $2$ and rest all $1$ which obviously gives a smaller sum.

However all the answers went with the latter approach. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your approach. I'll just explain otherwise.

Since $1994$ is nothing special, let's take the case of $n=3$ dice. Sum ranges from $3$ to $18$.

Note that $P(3)=P(18)$ as only one way for either {$(1,1,1)$ and $(6,6,6)$}.

Then $P(4)=P(17)$. Since $3$ ways to obtain either. {$(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,1,1)$} and {$(6,6,5),(6,5,6),(5,6,6)$}

Observe that $S=4$ can be obtained from $S=3$ by incrementing one of the $1$'s. And $S=17$ can be obtained from $S=18$ by decrementing one of the $6$'s. Also, the number of ways of incrementing $=$ number of ways of decrementing.

This is precisely the symmetry the second answer in your link points out.

Do you see now why the answer should be $337$?

Comment: I understood that, but why will the probability be same only when the sum is $7$? For example, if we roll say $n=5$ die the probability of getting three $3$s and two $5$s should be same as getting, say, three $6$s and two $4$s

Comment: Both should be exactly $\frac{10}{6^5}$ right?

Comment: I didn't get "only when the sum is 7". 
Yes both would be $\frac{10}{6^5}$.

Comment: P(333)=P(1998). P(334)=(P1997) ...

Comment: $cosmo5$ in your answer (and the ones in the link), you were replacing $5$ with $2$, $1$ with $6$, and so on only. What I am saying is that until the number of times any two numbers that rolls is same the probability is also same (which you seem to agree with) if that's the case and what I'm saying is right then we should roll $332$ $6$s and one $2$ to get least sum as only one number is different while otherwise we need $4$ numbers to be different according to the answers in the link. Final answer according to me should be $334$ not $337$

Comment: In fact we can just check and see; probability of rolling $332$ $6$s and one $2$ is $\frac{333}{6^{333}}$. The probability of rolling $332$ $1$s and one $2$ is also $\frac{333}{6^{333}}$ according to me. You can check that the sum comes out to be $1994$ in the first as it should and the second gives $334$ which should thus be the final answer.

Comment: 1994 can be obtained in multiple ways from 1998. By decrementing four 6's to four 5's or (three 6's to two 5's and one 4), one 6 to one 2 and so on.

Comment: yes, exactly and since we need the least sum the answer should be $334$ not $337$ as given on AoPS or according to other math.stack users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113708/discussion-between-cosmo5-and-l1mbo).

Comment: But it's highly unlikely they would make such a glaring mistake so I think we are making a mistake somewhere, and the only place I see it happening is in the calculations of the probability